# IN SQL CASE MULTIPLY WHEN MORE THAN IN DIFFERENT CRETERIA

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

HI I HAVE BELOW CODE I WANT WHEN SUM OF A.PP QTY IF YOU SEE IN BELOW I HAVE MENTION >= 2 AND >=5
WHEN MORE THAN FROM 2 THEN IT MUST MULTIPLY WITH 1000 AND WHEN 15 THEN 1500

```
select *,
case 


     when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001'
     and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march'  then
    case
        when sum(case when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001' and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march'
        then b.appqty end) over()   >= 2  then (b.AppQty * 1000)
    end

    when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001'
     and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march'  then
    case
        when sum(case when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001' and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march'
        then b.appqty end) over()   >= 5  then (b.AppQty * 1500)
    end

      end     DiscAmount
```

i want to multiply the value of b.appqty but its only multiplying with 1000 please help in this the multiplication of 1500 is not working

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Please.

Comment: desired result when qty more than 5 then multiply with 1500 when sum >=2 then 1000

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
(case when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001' and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march'  
      then (case when sum(case when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001' and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march' then b.appqty end) over () >= 5
                 then (b.AppQty * 1500)
                 when sum(case when b.SCode = 0202 and b.Itcoded = '37.01.123.0001' and b.MONTHOFDISC = 'march' then b.appqty end) over () >= 2
                 then (b.AppQty * 1000)
            end)
 end) as DiscAmount
```

Your version is much more complicated than necessary.  But the reason is because what is greater than 5 is also greater than 2, so the first condition always matches.  The key is to reverse the conditions to avoid this problem.

Comment: hello its not working for second creteria if >= 5 then 1500 its only allowing the >=2
Please

Comment: @MakhdoomLiaqat . . .There might be a typo, but for `>=5` it should use 1500 and for `>=2` and `<5` it should use 1000.  It is a bit hard for me to see how this could not be the case with this expression.  Perhaps you should set up a db/sql fiddle with sample data.

Comment: i have checked it again 
with value >= 5 at first
then >= 2 second its working correct in this case thank you dear my problem is solved